# Read memory value from dll + pointer + offsets

Tags: python, pointers, memory

I have the following address:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX3tA.png

If in the programm is the light on then there is a *one* otherwise a *zero*.
The programm process name is Win64-Test.exe.

In CE it works pretty well. Now I want to write a little python tool that watches for the light.

I have tried so far:

I have found via google this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hackManager/2.1.0 
It's primary for "game hacking" but I could use it for my purposes.

It reads out some values, but the wrong ones. The documentary is horribly of this tool and I could not figured out to point in the right memory.

some code that does not work:

```
from hackManager.hack import Hack

pointer = "Win64-Testl.dll" + 0x01009218 + 0x98 + 0x484
#
#
#

light_test_1 = instance.base_address
light_test_2 = pointer

target = "Win64-Test.exe"

instance = Hack(target)
print instance.base_address

print instance.read_char(light_test_1)
print instance.read_char(light_test_2)
```

I'm currently trying it to solve it with ctypes now, but I spent hours to figure out how to do it and had not any success yet.

Does someone have any tips or experience in things like that or can point me to the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the data as a "char" type. Ensure that this is the return value you want.

read_char
read_int
read_byte
read_word

are some possible alternatives.